# Postgre user without password and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with a user and a database owned by that user. A local program written in C uses that user to manipulate that database without a password. I want to use HTML and PHP to create a web interface to access that database.

I've read conflicting things about PostgreSQL and using it without passwords. I also don't want to interfere with the way the current software is accessing and manipulating the database without a password.

Do I simply add a password for that user to use as log-in information for the PHP queries? Is there a better way to securely access that database through PHP?

Comment: If you expose the database directly on the web through PHP, a password won't really help much, you'd be pwned before you can say SQL injection.

Comment: I'm wanting to use the database for user authentication. The existing C program uses the database in the same manner. I want to use it for a web application too.

Comment: So as I understand you have a current, working Client connecting directly with an app-user to the pg without password, and you do not wish to set a password for him. so stating "..to securely access that database.." is kinda like saying "how do I save my leg if I do not wish to remove the tourniquet"; The best advice I could give is to connect to the pgsql secure and trying to make obscure user names OR a web-app user and authenticate the user via app-login (additional PHP-only tables) using the PHP.

Comment: @adeneo What do you mean - use PHP only without DB? Or drop PHP?